# Haskell: merging list of lists

Tags: haskell

given a list of list pairs `::[a,a]`, I would like to return the possible combinations of lists, where the sublists have been merged on the last of one sublit matching head of the next.

for example 
    -- combine two lists if they front and back match

```
merge :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
merge (x:y:ys) | last x == head y = merge $ (x ++ (drop 1 y)) : ys
               | otherwise    = []
merge xs       = xs

combinations :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
combinations = nub . concatMap merge . permutations

λ= merge [1,2] [2,3]
[1,2,3]


-- there should be no duplicate results
λ= combinations [[1,3],[1,3],[1,3],[1,3],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2,2],[3,2],[3,2],[3,2]]
[[1,3,2,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3],[1,3,2,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,1,3],1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,2,1,3]]

-- the result must be a completely merged list or an empty list
λ= combinations [[1,3], [3,1], [2,2]]
[]

λ= combinations [[1,3], [3, 1]]
[[1,3,1],[3,1,3]]

λ= combinations [[1,3],[3,1],[3,1]]
[[3,1,3,1]]
```

I can't quite wrap my head around the recursion needed to do this efficiently.

Comment: It seems need to try all the permutations of elements of the list. And what happen if the list of pair say, `[[1,3], [3,1], [2,2]]` cannot be merged?

Comment: This resembles box stacking problem and it's not a simple thing since you get different results when you start with chaining up like `[1,3] -> [3,2] -> ..` or `[2,1] -> [1,3] -> ..`. Assuming that you want the least amount of sublists in the result, it can be solved efficiently by dynamical programming approaches. I think permutations will yield wasteful code here.

Comment: Could you define your problem better?. f.e. if the input is `[[1,3], [3, 1]]` up to your example the output should be `[[1,3,1]]` but up to your description, the output should be `[[1,3,1], [3,1,3]]`. Also if there are duplicates who do we proceed?  ex. if the input is `[[1,3],[3,1],[3,1]]` shouldn't the ouput be `[[1,3,1][1,3,1]]` instead of `[[1,3,1]]`?

Comment: @assembly.jc my original solution was to use `permutations` but this is obviously inefficient to the point of being impractical even in this small case

Comment: @LuisMorillo i have added more examples and my initial solutions. Duplicates are removed and `[[1,3],[3,1],[3,1]]`  should yield `[[3,1,3,1]]` since the sublists can be further combined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended with this solution, but it contains duplicates (you can use `Data.List(nub)` to get rid of them).

```
import Data.List(partition)

main :: IO ()
main =  do
        print $ show tmp

input = [[1,3],[1,3],[1,3],[1,3],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2,2],[3,2],[3,2],[3,2]]        

tmp = combinations input

-- this function turns list into list of pair, first element is element of the
-- input list, second element is rest of the list
each :: [a] -> [a] -> [(a, [a])]
each h [] = [] 
each h (x:xs) = (x, h++xs) : each (x:h) xs  

combinations :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
combinations l = concat $ map combine $ each [] l
   where
      -- take pair ("prefix list", "unused lists")
      combine :: (Eq a) => ([a], [[a]]) -> [[a]]
      combine (x, []) = [x]
      combine (x, xs) = let
                           l = last x
                           -- split unused element to good and bad
                           (g, b) = partition (\e -> l == head e) xs
                           s = each [] g
                           -- add on element to prefix and pass rest (bad + good except used element) to recursion. so it eat one element in each recursive call.
                           combine' (y, ys) = combine (x ++ tail y, ys ++ b) 
                        -- try to append each good element, concat result
                        in concat $ map combine' s
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work perfectly. I will try and understand it before I vote it up etc. Thanks

Comment: any chance you could add a little description to what you did?

Comment: @matthias added some comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you want to do, so here are just a few notes and hints.

> given a list of list pairs `::[a,a]`
>
> (...) for example
>
> `λ= merge [1,2] [2,3]`

Firstly those are not lists of pairs, each element of the list is an integer not a pair. They just happen to be lists with two elements. So you can say they are of type `[Int]` or an instance of type `[a]`.

> the sublists have been merged on the last of one sublit matching head of the next.

This suggests that the size of the lists will grow, and that you  will constantly need to inspect their first and last elements. Inspecting the last element of a list implies traversing it each time. You want to avoid that.

This suggests a representation of lists with extra information for easy access. You only need the last element, but I'll put first and last for symmetry.

```
-- lists together with their last element
data CL a = CL [a] a a 

cl :: [a] -> CL a 
cl [] = error "CL from empty list"
cl xs = CL xs (head xs) (last xs)

clSafe :: [a] -> Maybe (CL a)
clSafe [] = Nothing
clSafe xs = Just (cl xs)
 
clFirst (CL _ x _) = x
clLast  (CL _ _ x) = x

compatible cs ds = clLast cs == clFirst ds
```

Perhaps better, maybe you should have

```
data CL a = CL [a] a a | Nil
```

And to include an empty list that is compatible with all others.

Another point to take into account is that if e.g., you have a list `xs` and want to find lists `ys` to combine as `ys++xs`, then you want it to be very easy to access all `ys` with a given last element. That suggests you should store them in a  suitable structure. Maybe a hash table.

Comment: given a list of  two-element lists they want to link them *all* up at matching edges, and return all the possible ways of doing so. e.g. `linkUp [[1,2],[1,2]] ==> []`.

Comment: right, he wants to link them all, it was that bit I had missed